# Minecraft isn’t showing my installations on Arch Linux

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, linux, minecraft-launcher

I recently re-installed my laptop with Arch Linux and so naturally i installed the Minecraft launcher. I then made a symbolic link `~/.minecraft` pointing to the directory where i kept my minecraft saves on my old windows system (on the hard drive where i store all my files), however whenever i launch minecraft none of my installations appear there, i have correctly mounted the disk and i have all the appropriate permissions, can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the installations to the Minecraft Launcher, ensuring that the directory matches your `.minecraft` folder. When you start the installation, it will use the existing files.

The installation records are not connected to the file in the `.minecraft` folder. Deleting an installation does not remove the files that the installation uses. When you add a new installation, it’s doesn’t create the files until you try to launch it.

It’s also pointless to create multiple installations for the same version in the launcher, unless you want to use a different game directory for them.

Comment: If you're using different JVM arguments wouldn't that be a reason to use different installations?

Comment: Yeah, i think that’s a good reason to do so, but I have different installations because I use the Fabric modloader and I sometimes use forge (rarely), and i also use older versions from time to time,

Comment: Thanks, it worked after i restarted my system

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes It does like that if you wanna add a new one (problem finding your installation folder (and also make sure to also connect it to your minecraft folder)) you need ro delete one existing same minecraft versions installation such as optifine,forge and normal minecraft versions cannot be doubled